# Ajax in magento (load product view block)

Tags: php, ajax, magento

What I want to achieve:
Clicking on a product link/image (at least in certain areas) to open a pop-up with the full product information (basically all the contents of the product view page).

What I did/tried so far:

- created all the stuff outside the ajax php code (the module, links, templates, rewrites)
- created the ajax controller (which can be accessed with a link similar to: `http://test.com/index.php/ajaxproductview/ajax/index/id/2` ).
- to follow various tutorials ( like [this](http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-your-magento-modules-themes/) or [this](http://blog.decryptweb.com/ajax-in-magento/) ) - that helped me get this far. But I don't want to load my custom block, I want the default product view block(s).
- tried to add some code in the indexAction(). It gets there, but the code fails. I don't get any errors/notices/reports, just what it seems like an infinite loop that kills my processor.

  ```
  $body = $this
      ->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('product.info') // taken from catalog.xml
      ->toHtml();
  $this->getResponse()->setBody($body);
  ```

All the other pages work fine, and it's a fresh magento with only magneto and my module installed and activated.

My AJAX function simply gets this HTML response, puts it into a div, and opens a pop-up.

My question(s) is(are) - how can I set the product id, so the block knows what product to load, and how can I load this block correctly. I also tried something similar to this:

Thank you.

PS: I also tried this:

```
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $update->load('catalog_product_view');
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput(); // $output is an empty string
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Product controller uses a helper to set the active product. You should be able to do the same in your controller!

Try this before you do your layouting:

```
$productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProduct($productId, $this);
```

Another thing to be aware of:
If you add a block like the product.info block. It needs additional child blocks if it calls them in its template file.

It would be easiest to use a custom layout xml file. You can then add a specific layout for your action handle (your action handle consists of your routers node in your module's etc/config.xml file under `<frontend><routers>`, e.g. `<Yourmodule>` node, make sure to lowercase it! And then with underscores add the controller name and action name, in your case index_index) like this:

```
<yourmodule_index_index>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="root" output="toHtml" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    <!-- Add all the child blocks you need -->
    </block>
</yourmodule_index_index>
```

This makes the view.phtml the root block which renders itself using its toHtml method.
Therefore, in your controller action, all you need is my two lines above and then:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: allright, so basically I would need to add those blocks as well, basically replicate to structure in the XML in the controller, correct ?

Comment: @VladPreda Yes, correct. Easiest would be to add your own xml layout file in your module. Then add the blocks to your specific action handle like "<yourmodule_index_index>...</yourmodule_index_index>". I will update my question with regards to this.

Comment: @VladPreda Elaborated on this.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. it's working perfectly. It seems I tried something similar, but was missing name="root" and output="toHtml"

Comment: Following everything described here has helped me tremendously! I now have the problem where I can't seem to access the product object from within my custom template, even though I have set it up with the line Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProduct($productId, $this) in my controller. (the product child blocks display correctly). I was wondering what call everyone made to get access to it?

Comment: I figured it out. Adding Mage::register($product,'product') in my controller, then assigning $_product = Mage::registry('product') in my template enables me to access the product object set up in the controller from within my template.

Comment: @mpaepper Thank you for the insights. It helped.