# Magnento load product view via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

What I want to achieve: Clicking on a product link/image (at least in certain areas) to open a pop-up with the full product information (basically all the contents of the product view page).

I've attempted to implement the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394960/ajax-in-magento-load-product-view-block), but I get a white page instead of returning the product. If I visit the named route directly I get a fully rendered version of our website with Magento's 'polling' feature in the main content area.

What I have is below. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I updated my Config and Layout XML based on a link @Marius provided. Instead of getting a fully rendered page when visiting the named route I get the template I specified -but not the product. I am completely stumped.

**Ajax** (using jQuery in no-conflict mode)

```
<div id="magic"><p>Hi</p></div>
<pre id="result"></pre>
<script>
    var loadUrl = '/shopthelook/ajax/index';
    jQuery("#magic").click(function(){
    jQuery("#result")
        .load(loadUrl, null, function(responseText){
            jQuery('#result').text("Response:\n" + responseText);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller** - I've hardcoded the ID for testing purposes.

```
class PM_ShopTheLook_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $id = 52986;
        Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProduct($id, $this);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <PM_ShopTheLook>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </PM_ShopTheLook>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <shopthelook>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>PM_ShopTheLook</module>
                    <frontName>shopthelook</frontName>
                </args>
            </shopthelook>
        </routers>
        <layout>
             <updates>
                <shopthelook_layout>
                    <file>shop_the_look.xml</file>
                 </shopthelook_layout>
             </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <shopthelook_ajax_index>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="root" output="toHtml" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">

        </block>
    </shopthelook_ajax_index>
</layout>**
```

Comment: can you please use this `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` instead of `Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProduct($id, $this);`

Comment: are you sure product is loading? check printing the product details in controller.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/2800/146 maybe you can get something out of it.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Yes, the product is loading. Whether I use the helper or the model I get product data.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, I've looked at that too. The OP is further along than I am -I can't even get the product to display.